# ABI encoding with tuples

Tags: abi, encoding, abiencoderv2

I don't understand how ABI encoding with tuples work:

`f(uint8[], uint)` with arguments `[3], 4` accordingly https://abi.hashex.org produces:

`479587820000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000040000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000400000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000003`

1. In arguments the value 3 goes before 4, but in the encoded 4 is before 3. In some reason, the value 3 is at the very end despite it is in the first element. Why?!
2. First go all the heads, then all the tails, right? Each head is a 32 bytes offset to the corresponding tail from the beginning of the tuple, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Strictly speaking, there are no tuples in your example.  Type `uint8[]` is a dynamic array type, not a tuple.  Here is the encoding decomposed:

```
47958782                                                         // Function selector (4 bytes)
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000040 // Offset of the first argument (32 bytes)
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000004 // Value of the second argument (32 bytes)
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001 // Length of the array (offset points here, 32 bytes)
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000003 // First element of the array (32 bytes)
```